# Meaning of "roll down" in "Bill and I rolled down the runway not knowing whether this airplane would leave the runway in a controlled manner"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrases

In a book I'm reading there is a phrase "roll down" as follows:

> When we checked the airplane again in the morning, it had been repaired - it turned out two wires had been crossed. My RIO, Bill Mnich, and I **rolled down** the runway that morning not knowing for sure whether this airplane would leave the runway in a controlled manner.

I don't understand the meaning of the phrase **rolled down** here.

Please explain to me. Thanks

Comment: A very good question. +1. I had heard *rolling down windows.* I'm curious to know how does one roll down the runway! :)

Comment: The book is Endurance, by Scott Kelly if you want to know :)

Comment: Please consider [waiting longer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an idiomatic usage of the verb *roll* that roughly means *move, cruise, travel*:

> [roll](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll)
>   5 c : to move on wheels
>   (M-W)

This usage of *down* roughly means *along*, as in *we walked **down** the street*. It is not necessarily indicating any kind of descent in this example.

> [down](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/down)
>   20. in a descending or more remote direction or place on, over, or along: They ran off down the street.
>   (Dictionary.com)

The example sentence roughly means

> My RIO, Bill Mnich, and I *moved along* the runway...

Comment: Well, separating the two words makes it easy to crack. The problem was to consider that as a *phrasal verb.*

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't see it as a phrasal verb. Maybe there's a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

More specific to the other answer, when a plane **rolls down the runway**, it is gaining acceleration just prior to taking off.

From [*The Night Eagles Soared*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=2iLNNgBx2kcC&pg=PA96&dq=%22roll%20down%20the%20runway%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKvOaryb7cAhUq_IMKHaoDAU8Q6AEI2wEwHw#v=onepage&q=%22roll%20down%20the%20runway%22&f=false):

[image: The Night Eagles Soared]

So, in the book in question, when the plane is **rolling down the runway**, it is in the process of taking off and the protagonist is uncertain how well it will perform.

In comparison, when a plane **taxis down the runway** it is only moving at a slow manoeuvring speed. A plane taxis from the hangar down the runway to the point at which it stops while waiting for takeoff. (Or it taxis down the runway from where it lands back to the hangar.)